# SQL - Query Basic between 2 tables

Tags: sql

I would like to know in MYSQL (editor HeidiSQL)

I have 2 Tables (email & spam) 2 rows (ID, EMAIL) and i want to clean my database :
Tables Used in Set Operation Examples

```
                                EMAIL

                                  x  y
                           ------------------
                                  1  one@edu.com     
                                  2  two@edu.com     
                                  2  two@edu.com      
                                  3  three@edu.com    

                                SPAM

                                  x  z
                           ------------------
                                  1  one@edu.com      
                                  2  two@edu.com      
                                  4  four@edu.com
```

USUALLY i use EXCEPT but it doesn't work on MYSQL.

proc sql;
   title 'EMAIL EXCEPT SPAM'
   select * from sql.EMAIL
   except
   select * from sql.SPAM;

Producing Rows That Are in Only the First Query Result (EXCEPT)

```
                               EMAIL EXCEPT SPAM

                                  x  y
                           ------------------
                                  3  three@edu.com
```

i try to use WHERE NOT EXISTS but i don't know.

Can you help me for making the query :

SELECT *
FROM EMAIL
WHERE ... ????

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM EMAIL WHERE y NOT IN (SELECT z FROM SPAM)
```

Answer (score 2):

Left Outer Join with Null in spam should work.

```
SELECT E.*
FROm EMAIL E
LEFT JOIN SPAM S
  ON E.Email = S.Email
WHERE S.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> USUALLY i use EXCEPT but it doesn't work on MYSQL.

`EXCEPT` is not supported in mySQL. Note that in absence of an explicit `ALL | DISTINCT` keyword, `EXCEPT` defaults to `EXCEPT DISTINCT`. Therefore, in your workaround you should explicitly use `SELECT DISTINCT` (because `SELECT` defaults to `SELECT ALL`).

> i try to use WHERE NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT DISTINCT y 
  FROM EMAIL 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM SPAM
                     WHERE y = z );
```